# How to Create Application using Spring Boot to read XLS File and Stored in Database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, xls

is there any way,that we can read XLS File from the HTML and stores in Database(Using Spring Boot)

Kindly Help me in providing some reference links so that, i will learn and implement 
Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be adding more details your question, nevertheless adding links as per my understanding of your question.

You can go for Apache POI to read the Excel file in Java, Reference URL as below:

```
https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-excel-file-apache-poi/
```

Spring tutorials for the upload file is as below:

```
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-excel-files
```